# How do I test orientation lock in iOS8 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

If I recall correctly I could set the orientation lock in the iOS Simulator before XCode 6. Now it appears this option is no longer available. Is it somewhere else?

Note: I'm testing web apps that adjust to orientation. They need to do different things if the user has the orientation locked vs unlocked and so I need to test. I could have sworn I was able to test this on iOS7.1 simulator in XCode 5 but it seems that option is missing in XCode 6.

Is there a way to test this in the simulator?

Comment: Just don't rotate the device when you're in the simulator?

Comment: The device still reports rotation, it just doesn't rotate the display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you slide up control center, you can click on the rotation lock button to lock rotation.

Comment: So obvious after the fact :D

Comment: Not available in Simulator 10.0.

Comment: There is no such thing as control center in iOS Simulator, it's just a blank screen. Solve it, please!

Comment: Yes, recent versions of iOS broke this functionality.  Please file a radar to help "upvote" the regression!

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia do you have a link to the radar?

Comment: This was a loooong time ago.  If you are seeing this today, please file a new radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current versions of iOS, this cannot be done. Writing this May 2023, the current version is 16.5.

Moreover, there is no orientation lock. Rather, it is portrait lock. That means that if using an app such as Apple Maps in landscape orientation, on enabling portrait lock, the orientation will change to portrait.

See [Rotate the screen on your iPhone or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204547).

To complicate matters further, on the simulator, swiping down from top right reveals Control Center but without controls. Only carrier, network, and battery life are visible.

See related question [Cannot open iPhone Control Center on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816794/cannot-open-iphone-control-center-on-simulator).