# UICollectionView dynamic header size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, dynamic-type-feature

I have a collectionView with a header designed in a .xib file. It has a simple label and it's text supports dynamicType.

How can I set the height of that header to be dynamic based on that label and the auto layout constraints in Storyboard?

So far, I've got this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let kind = UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)
    if let headerView = collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: kind, at: indexPath) as? SectionHeaderView {
        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        headerView.setNeedsLayout()
        let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        return size
    }
    return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

**But it does not show any header.**

SectionHeaderView.xib looks like this:
[image: header.xib]

CollectionView looks like this: you see 3 sections, but you don't see a header.
[image: collectionView]

**What can I do to let AutoLayout determine the correct hight of the header?**

Answer (score 0):

Use a **custom flow layout** to perfectly manage the height of a header in a collection view with the `Dynamic Type` feature.

A header element is seen as a **supplementary element** for a collection view and the `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` 'method' is only used for initialization: it's not called with the `Dynamic Type` feature.

The solution hereafter is based on the `layoutAttributesForElements` method of the custom layout that will be able to adapt the header height thanks to the `UIFontMetrics` [`scaledValue`](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#ScaledValue).

All that is fired by the `invalidateLayout` method called in the [`traitCollectionDidChange`](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#text-size) triggered when the user changes the font size.

**STEP 1** ⟹ create a simple custom header class as follows for instance:

```
class MyHeaderClass: UICollectionReusableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame) }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }
}
```

**STEP 2** ⟹ create a new empty .xib adding a reusable view and name it the exact same name as the class it refers to: don't forget to change its class name in the `Identity Inspector`.

**STEP 3** ⟹ register the .xib file in the controller:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier bundle: nil),
                        forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,
                        withReuseIdentifier:collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)
```

**STEP 4** ⟹ support this new cell in your data source *(a header is a supplementary element for a collection view)*:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader) {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                                                                         withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderReuseIdentifier,
                                                                         for: indexPath) as! MyHeader
        headerView.myLabel.text = "Your Header Title"
        return headerView
    } else {
        return UICollectionReusableView(frame: CGRect.null) }
}
```

... and in your delegate *(this intializes the header size and makes it appear)*:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: headerHeight)
}
```

.. after adding a global `var headerHeight: CGFloat = 90.0` for initialization.

**STEP 5** ⟹ create the custom flow layout to adapt the header height to the new font size:

```
class FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        layoutAttributes?.forEach({ (attribute) in
            if (attribute.representedElementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader) {

                headerHeight = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 22.0)
                attribute.frame.size.height = headerHeight
            }
        })

        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Don't forget to update the storyboard in `Interface Builder`:
[image]
**STEP 6** ⟹ inform the controller to trigger a layout update when the user changes the font size:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if (previousTraitCollection?.preferredContentSizeCategory != traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory) {
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Following this rationale, **the correct height of the headers is automatically set up according to the headers font size** ⟹ I suggest to use the [Xcode 11 new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080491/3825084) to test the `Dynamic Type` very quickly.

Comment: I followed everything and it did not worked for me.

Comment: don't forget to call super `super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you've got the proper constraints setup for your header, and you return a dynamically deduced height in your `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`:

Observe `UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification` in your class:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fontSizeChanged), name: UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Use your `fontSizeChanged` function for updation:

```
@objc private func fontSizeChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    //If you're dealing with minimal data, you can simply 'reloadData()'
    //If not, I'm sure there are other efficient ways to make this work. I'm just exposing the provision
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Oh, and make sure you:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```